# How tkinter and ttk works in python 3.5?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

i am learning Python and i have a question about .grid() method.
In the example the author gave, he is making imports with an * like so:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, messagebox
import base64
import json
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

then, he creates the root window, and the main frame, like this:

```
_root = Tk() # tkinter object, main window
_root.title('Scrape app') # window title
_root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
_mainframe = ttk.Frame(_root, padding='5 5 5 5')
_mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(E, W, N, S))
```

So far so good, i catch it all. The problem begins when he says that importing with * is not a good practice because of names collisions, so in one of my attempts to create something similar thinking of good practice, i did this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, filedialog
import base64
import json
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

    root_window = tk.Tk()
    root_window.title('My first attemp of custom guiscrape')
    root_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    # First Frame
    g_main_frame = ttk.Frame(root_window, padding='5 5 5 5')
    g_main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSWE')
    g_url_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(g_main_frame, text='URL', padding='5 5 5 5')
    g_url_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='EW')
    g_url_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    g_url_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    var_url = tk.StringVar()
    var_url.set('http://localhost:8000')
    g_url_entry = ttk.Entry(g_url_frame, width=40, textvariable=var_url)
    g_url_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NESW', padx=5)
    root_window.mainloop()
```

The issue here is when _mainframe.grid() appears, the sticky option gets a tuple with four constants, in the author's example, but when i try giving a tuple in my attempt i get an error, constant E is not defined, so i have to use a string like 'NEWS', differing a lot from author's approach (N, E, W, S).

Is it a difference with the grid method from tkinter and ttk? what could be the best approach to use it? i can't find more documentation about ttk that can solve my doubt, Hope you can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because those also are part of `tkinter`.  You need to use `(tk.N, tk.E, tk.W, tk.S)`

Comment: Thank you so much! you are a lifesaver!, didn't see that coming. Where can i check for more information about tkinter and ttk? and, is it better to stick with it? or to use pyQt? i read about it but i'm new to Python!

Comment: You can always use the built-in `help()` function: `help('tkinter')`.  From the command-line, use `pydoc`: `pydoc tkinter`.  As for the library recommendation, I've used only `tkinter` and `PyGTK+`.  I wouldn't recommend `PyGTK+` for you at this stage, so I can't really help you on that one.